# Не понятные свойства описанные в хедере сайта на движке Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте! Изучаю код сайта на битриксе и не могу разобраться, что могут значить эти три строчки, прописанные в хедере? Что это за свойства страницы?

Кто работает с битриксом, подскажите пожалуйста их значение и как они могут влиять на работу сайта? Заранее спасибо!

```
<?$APPLICATION->ShowProperty("yandexv")?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowProperty("googlev")?>
<?$APPLICATION->ShowProperty("noindex")?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вывод значений свойств страницы или раздела по типу `ShowTitle`. При работе этой функции используются отложенные функции и значение может быть установлено в любом месте с помощью функции `SetPageProperty` или `SetDirProperty`.

С помощью этих вызовов устанавливаются дополнительные теги для гугла и яндекса, а так же запрет на индексацию страницы.

Редактировать можно через редактирование свойства страницы.

Comment: т.е. получается, что эта страница не индексируется? И что значит дополнительные теги для гугла и яндекса? Прошу прощения, если вопрос прозвучит глупо. Битрикс для меня терра инкогнито

Comment: @Alla это не стандартный функционал битрикса эти свойства кто то доделал. Зайдите в исходный код какой либо страницы и переключайте эти параметры в свойствах страницы и посмотрите что меняется. и нет не факт что страница не индексируется просто есть возможность что бы она не индексировалась